# Does Mac OSX software raid support partial resync?

Tags: macos, raid, software-raid, resync

If I have a software RAID-1 (mirror) setup in Mac OSX and I turn off the system during mirror rebuild, when I turn it back on will it start a whole new resync or just do a partial resync (like linux' raid1 or drbd where both store a bitmap of already-synched blocks)?

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it intentionally. I suspect the RAID will show as degraded and try to pick up where it left off.